# How do getter methods work on arrays?

Tags: java, getter

```
public class foo {

private int a[];
private int b;

public foo(){
    a = new int[] {1,2};
    b= 3;
}

public int[] getA(){
    return this.a;
}

public int getB(){
    return this.b;
}
```

I noticed that it's possible to change a value of A by accessing the object like this:

```
foo f = new foo();
f.getA()[0] = 5; // f.a[0] changes to 5
```

but it isn't possible to do something like:

```
f.getB = 5; // gives error
f.getA() = new int[]{2,3};  //gives error
```

can someone explain me how this works, and how to prevent the user from changing the value of an array cell?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All java parameters and results are passed by value.  Including arrays.  But the value that is passed (for a reference type) is the reference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51426788/setters-and-getters-for-arrays/51427122

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java, array is a reference type, which means that the value of an array expression is a reference to the actual array.

The return value of `getA()` is, therefore, a reference to the private array inside your object. This breaks encapsulation: you give access to your object's internals.

You can avoid this by either returning a reference to a *copy* of your internal array, or by providing a different API which only returns individual elements, say a method `getA(int index)`.

Comment: Or OP could *not* use an array, but an immutable collection instead, like Guava's `ImmutableList` for example.

Comment: Your suggestion amounts to using a 3rd-party implementation of the same idea (`ImmutableList` still uses an array on the inside).

Comment: Yes. I was just trying to complement your answer, not dispute it.

Comment: If we were nitpicking, there would also be the issue of a sixfold increase in memory consumption when going from `int` to `Integer`. But perhaps Guava has primitive type specializations for its immutable containers?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Not for immutable containers, but `Collections.unmodifiableList(Ints.asList(array))` would do.

Answer (score 2):

`f.get(A)` returns a reference to an array. You can access that array the way you access any array, and assign values to its elements with `f.get(A)[i]=...` (though it makes more sense to store the returned array in a variable, which would let you access that array multiple times, without having to call `f.get(A)` each time).

You can't, however, assign anything `f.get(A)` via `f.get(A)=..`, since a method call is not a valid left side of an assignment operator. For all you know, a call to `f.get(A)` may generate a new array that is not referred to by a member of the `foo` class, so assigning `f.get(A)= new int[5];` would make no sense, since there would be no variable in which to store the new array.
The same explanation applies to `f.getB() = 5;`.

Comment: Good mentioning left side assignment which is in my eyes the important aspect ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving away the array, to allow the caller to do what they like with it you can use an indexed getter

```
public int getA(int n){
    return this.a[n];
}

public void setA(int n, int x) {
    this.a[n] = x;
}
```

Now, the caller has no access to the array and cannot change it without you knowing.