# Setters and getters for arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java and I need some clarification how to approach an issue.

I have a class `Epicycle`, defined below:

```
public class Ts_epicycle {
    private double epoch;
    private double[] tle = new double[10];
}
```

In another class, `Refine` I am calling a method that requires the `tle` array:

```
// create an instance of Epicycle
Epicycle e = new Epicycle();

methodExample(keps1, keps2, e.tle);
```

In methodExample, I would be setting the array values for `tle`

1) What is best way for creating getters/setters for the `tle` array? (and for the other variable too).

2) In the methodExample, I need to pass in the argument for the whole `tle` array rather than any particular index of it. How would I go about this.

Apologies if i'm not making it clear.

Comment: tle is already thread safe as it is a non static variable and you are creating an instance of Epicycle everytime in your function

Comment: In case you are planning to provide referene of an array to another thread, consider using read and write lock . http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/readwritelock.html

Answer (score 5):

In fact an interesting question:

In order that altering entries in the gotten array does not alter the original object,
you would need to return a **copy** of the array. *Not so nice.*

```
public class TsEpicycle {
    private double epoch;
    private double[] tle = new double[10];

    public double[] getTLE() {
        return Arrays.copyOf(tle, tle.length);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use the List class instead of an array:

```
public class TsEpicycle {
    private double epoch;
    private List<Double> tle = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Double> getTLE() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(tle);
    }
}
```

This does not make a copy, but simple disallows at run-time to alter the list.
Here the inefficiency is in the Double objects wrapping doubles.

The best might be to use the new Stream class: for iterating through the doubles:

```
public class TsEpicycle {
    private double epoch;
    private double[] tle = new double[10];

    public DoubleStream getTLE() {
        return Stream.of(tle);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use `tle.clone()` for a copy of the array, which wouldn't need `import java.util.Arrays`.

Comment: @Leponzo is right, that also does away with the length argument. I avoid clone (class related), but on arrays there is no reason.

Answer (score 1):

As a general best practice every field in a class that you need to access from another class should be provided with a *getter* and (if the object is intended as mutable) a *setter*.

As well explained by **Joop Eggen** in his answer is usually a good practice to return a copy or a proxy (for example a List/Collection referencing the array), in order to preserve the state of the original array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only allow users to edit the array one at a time, then you can add the `synchronized` keyword to the method signature. Accessing an array is already thread safe so you don't need anything there

For example:

```
double getTle(int index) {
    return tle[index]
}

synchronized void setTle(int index, double value) {
    tle[index] = value;
}
```

This only allows the method to be called once at a time

Answer (score 0):

**your array is an object like any other object in java .**

```
// to declare and initialize your array

private int[] st = new int[10];

//getter and setter 

public int[] getSt() {
        return st;
    }
public void setSt(int[] st) {
        this.st = st;
    }

//for the last method u can use 

public void method(int value)
{
for(int i = 0 ; i<st.lenght ; i++){
st[i] += value; // for exemple
}
```